# A PhoneGap Build plugin isn't present in the app's environment

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I added the following to config.xml, as instructed.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" version="4.1.0" source="npm" />
```

Restarted the server, reconnected the iOS app. I'm told the only thing left to do is to call `window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()`. Here's the [documentation for the plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-insomnia). It's just meant to keep the screen "awake."

So I wrapped the code in trycatch and the error is:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   `window.plugins.insomina`)

Looks like it never makes it. The docs make it seem like adding the line to config.xml is all that's needed, and the phonegap server (I'm using the server/app thing they have available for development).

Do I need to manually move the files or something, if so, why?

Comment: When are you making that call? Is it after the deviceready event?

Comment: Also, try 4.2.0 version.

Comment: @utamanna I changed to 4.2.0 (errday) and I think my mistake was that it was included in the www folder's config.xml and not root config.xml - a bit confusing why there's two. Either way, doesn't seem to error out now. Feel free to add the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Oh it's okay, I don't think I helped much there, you solved that all by yourself. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Are you using Phonegap Desktop App?